# cannot call bash environment variable inside jq

Tags: bash, jq

In the below script, I am not able to successfully call the "repovar" variable in the jq command.

```
cat quayrepo.txt | while read line
do
  export repovar="$line"
  jq -r --arg repovar "$repovar" '.data.Layer| .Features[] | "\(.Name), \(.Version), $repovar"' severity.json > volume.csv
done
```

The script uses a text file to loop through the repo names

quayrepo.txt---> file has the list of names in this case the file has a value of `"Reponame1"`

sample input severity.json file:

```
{
  "status": "scanned",
  "data": {
    "Layer": {
      "IndexedByVersion": 3,
      "Features": [
        {
          "Name": "elfutils",
          "Version": "0.168-1",
          "Vulnerabilities": [
            {
              "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
              "Severity": "Medium",
              "Name": "CVE-2016-2779"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

desired output:

```
elfutils, 0.168-1, Medium, Reponame1
```

Required output: I need to retrieve the value of my environment variable as the last column in my output csv file

Comment: Please include sample input and desired output.

Comment: You probably want `>>` instead of `>` as the latter will overwrite whatever was written before.

Comment: @vintnes- made the edits... let me know if you need any further info

Comment: @peak--- sorry the question is not about overwriting the output file

Comment: while we're nitpicking: 
`while read line; do ...; done < quayrepo.txt`

Comment: Heck, `while read -r repovar; do` -- why use a `line` variable at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to surround $repovar with parenthesis, as the other values

```
repovar='qweqe'; jq -r --arg repovar "$repovar" '.data.Layer| .Features[] | "\(.Name), \(.Version), \($repovar)"' tmp.json
```

Result:

```
elfutils, 0.168-1, qweqe
```

There's no need for the `export`.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line
do
  jq -r --arg repovar "$line" '.data.Layer.Features[] | .Name + ", " + .Version + ", " + $repovar' severity.json
done < quayrepo.txt > volume.csv
```

with `quayrepo.txt` as

```
Reponame1
```

and `severity.json` as

```
{
  "status": "scanned",
  "data": {
    "Layer": {
      "IndexedByVersion": 3,
      "Features": [
        {
          "Name": "elfutils",
          "Version": "0.168-1",
          "Vulnerabilities": [
            {
              "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
              "Severity": "Medium",
              "Name": "CVE-2016-2779"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

produces `volume.csv` containing

```
elfutils, 0.168-1, Reponame1
```

To @peak's point, changing `>` to `>>` in `...severity.json >> volume.csv` will create a multi-line csv instead of just overwriting until the last line

Comment: Better to just put `> volume.csv` after the `done`, not on the individual `jq` line. That way each `jq` call appends, but the loop as a whole clears any prior content when starting -- and you have (ever-so-slightly) better performance since you aren't re-opening the output file over and over, as you do with `>> volume.csv` on the individual `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `while read` loop in bash at all; `jq` itself can loop over your input lines, even when they aren't JSON, letting you run `jq` only once, not once per line in `quayrepo.txt`.

```
jq -rR --slurpfile inJson severity.json <quayrepo.txt >volume.csv '
($inJson[0].data.Layer | .Features[]) as $features |
[$features.Name, $features.Version, .] |
@csv
'
```

- `jq -R` specifies raw input, letting jq directly read lines from `quayrepo.txt` into `.`
- `jq --slurpfile varname filename.json` reads `filename.json` into an array of JSON objects parsed from that file. If the file contains only one object, one needs to refer to `$varname[0]` to refer to it.
- `@csv` converts an array to a CSV output line, correctly handling data with embedded quotes or other oddities that require special processing.